# Imprimir un formulario c# con un tamaño de hoja (abierto)

Tags: c#, print

Quisiera generar un informe a travez de un "Form" de windows, Generar un informe utilizando el mismo diseñador de formulario del Visual Studio, y de esta forma imprimir un informe, con labels, textbox y listview. Deacuerdo a al siguiente informe
[Como imprimir un formulario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-windows-form?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
El problema con esta idea es que no sé cómo generar el tamaño exacto a realizar del formulario.
El tamaño de hoja legal o Oficio en Píxeles es el siguiente (816, 1344), pero al intentar poner este tamaño en el formulario, no puedo generar el tamaño anteriormente dicho.

**Actualizacion**

Estoy utilizando Un Usercontrol, que si me deja modificar el tamaño al anteriomente dicho, pero al intentar imprimir, hace una capura de pantalla y no hace una impresion de dicho componente.

Intento llamar al usercontrol, desde un form, sin realizar un "show", y utilizol la siguiente funcion:

```
private Bitmap ControlaImagen(System.Windows.Forms.Control theControl)
{
    
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(theControl.Width, theControl.Height);
    theControl.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, theControl.Width, theControl.Height));
    return bm;           
}
```

Simplemente asigno a una variable el Usercontrol y luego lo paso por la funcion anterior
Y luego lo intento imprimir con el siguiente evento de printpage, de un PrintDocument

```
private void Cuponaimprimir_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(ControlaImagen(New cupon()), 0, 0);}
```

Porque puede ser que no redenrisa el formulario y lo envia a imagen ?
He intentado con Refresh, Update, Voids de Usercontrol, y nada

Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?, gracias

Comment: creo que hay que deshabilitar una propiedad que impide esos tamaños, déjame la busco y te confirmo

Comment: esto debe de servirte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694505/8166997

Comment: No me sirve porque lo que hace es extender los tamaños, en tiempo de ejecución! yo lo que necesitaría es extender el tamaño en tiempo de edición

Comment: Si quieres hacer un informe pq no usas el ReportViewer

Comment: Uso el IDE INTELLIJ IDEA, RIDER, lo cual no es compatible con rldc editor